How to implement "Bind customers to sales channel" functionality in shopware 6
I'm working on a Shopware 6 project and I'm trying to implement a feature to optionally bind customers to sales channels. I have a custom component that extends sw-customer-base-info.
I want to implement a feature similar to the "Bind customers to sales channel" toggle that should be in Settings > Login / Registration. When this option is inactive, I need to set the bound_sales_channel_id to NULL when editing the sales channel.
I initially tried to access this setting through the system configuration, but it seems that the configuration key core.loginRegistration.bindCustomerToSalesChannel doesn't exist. Here's what I get when I output the configuration:
{
    "core.loginRegistration.confirmationUrl": "/registration/confirm?em=%%HASHEDEMAIL%%&hash=%%SUBSCRIBEHASH%%",
    "core.loginRegistration.invalidateSessionOnLogOut": false,
    "core.loginRegistration.passwordMinLength": "8",
    "core.loginRegistration.pwdRecoverUrl": "/account/recover/password?hash=%%RECOVERHASH%%",
    "core.loginRegistration.requireDataProtectionCheckbox": false,
    "core.loginRegistration.unusedGuestCustomerLifetime": 86400
}

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:
Shopware.Component.override('sw-customer-base-info', {
    // ... other component code ...

    methods: {
        async updateBoundSalesChannel(newSalesChannelId) {
            try {
                const customer = await this.customerRepository.get(this.customer.id, Shopware.Context.api);
                
                if (this.isCustomerBindingEnabled) {
                    customer.boundSalesChannelId = newSalesChannelId;
                } else {
                    customer.boundSalesChannelId = null;
                }

                await this.customerRepository.save(customer, Shopware.Context.api);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error updating boundSalesChannelId:', error);
            }
        }
    }
});

How can I properly update the bound_sales_channel_id based on this setting when editing a customer's sales channel?
